# Cannot clear timer inside a timers array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with Javascript timers. Basically, I have these 2 page elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
<input type="button id="clearAll" value="Clear Timers" />
```

And the following Javascript that manages them:

```
// store all page timers here
var timers = new Array(); 

// clears all page timers
function clearTimers () {
    console.log("Clearing all timers.")
    for (var i = 0; i< timers.length; i++)
            clearTimeout (timers[i]);
}

// does stuff
function foo (whichTimer, interval) {
    console.log("I am timer " + whichTimer + " running once every " + interval);
}

// document load
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#clearAll").click(clearTimers);

// check status at document load
if ( $("input#chk").is(':checked') )
{
        console.log("Input checked at start. Creating refresh.")
        t1 = setInterval("foo(1, 2000)", 2000);
        timers.push(t1); // add our timer to array
        console.log("Index of t1 is: " + timers.indexOf(t1));
}
else
{
    console.log("Input not checked at start.");
    clearTimeout(t1); //optional
}

// refresh toggle click handler
$("input#chk").click( function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
        console.log("Input got checked.");
        if (!t1) {
            console.log("We don't have a t1 yet. Creating.")
            t1 = setInterval("foo(1, 2000)", 2000);
            timers.push(t1); // add our timer to array
            console.log("Index of t1 is: " + timers.indexOf(t1));
        }
        else {
            console.log("t1 already exists and is clear. Setting new timeout.");
            t1 = setInterval("foo(1,2000)", 2000);
            console.log("Index of t1 is: " + timers.indexOf(t1));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log ("Input got unchecked. Clearing t1.");
        clearTimeout(t1);
        console.log("Index of t1 is: " + timers.indexOf(t1));
    }
});

}
```

I have a webpage whose content changes dynamically (including main page content), so any old timers must be eliminated when changing the content. So I went for the old timer array trick to do this.

This example shows a checkbox that toggles an automatic refresh of the page, and seems to work correctly when used independently.

The only problem I have is that once the refresh is active (i.e `t1` has a `setInterval` in effect), the `clearTimers()` function fails to stop the active timer.

Here is a sample console output to see what I'm talking about:

```
Input not checked at start.
Input got checked.
We don't have a t1 yet. Creating.
Index of t1 is: 0
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
Input got unchecked. Clearing t1.
Index of t1 is: 0
Input got checked.
t1 already exists and is clear. Setting new timeout.
Index of t1 is: 0
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
Input got unchecked. Clearing t1.
Index of t1 is: -1 <--------------- This is what starts to worry me
Input got checked.
t1 already exists and is clear. Setting new timeout.
Index of t1 is: -1
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
Clearing all timers.
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
I am timer 1 running once every 2000
Input got unchecked. Clearing t1. <------- Need to uncheck the box to stop the timer
Index of t1 is: -1
```

Also notice how `Array.indexOf(t1)` first returns 0, then -1 after the same set of operations. This being said:

Question 1: Why does this happen?

Question 2: What can I do for my code to work properly?

Comment: Your code is riddled with syntax and reference errors.

Answer (score 7):

You're using `setInterval()` and then trying to `clearTimeout()`

If you're wanting to clear an interval, use `clearInterval()`

```
var i = setInterval(foo, 1000);
clearInterval(i);

var t = setTimeout(foo, 1000);
clearTimeout(t);
```

Comment: I still get the -1 glitch (see console example) regardless of `clearTimeout()` or `clearInterval()`. I suspect that the reference to t1 inside the array is lost for some reason. But I can't figure out why.

Comment: @AndreiSuceava because you're not pushing `t1` to the array in your `"t1 already exists and is clear. Setting new timeout."` condition.

Comment: Big thanks Shmiddty! You were right. I did some research and `Array.indexOf()` actually compares the object values. That's why my references didn't work properly. Even though I get an ever-growing `t1` index in `timers`, it's not a big problem because: 1) I don't think anybody will abuse the refresh box a gazillion times 2) When doing the `clearTimers()` it's easy to clear up the orphaned references as well. Submit your answer and I'll vote it! :)

Comment: Oops, got you guys mixed up. :) Gabe: +1 for syntax fix, Shmiddty vote for your answer.

Comment: This would be only a readability issue according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout):  

_It's worth noting that the pool of IDs used by setTimeout() and    setInterval() are shared, which means you can technically use clearTimeout() and clearInterval() interchangeably. However, for clarity, you should avoid doing so._